# How to get data from an XML file with xmlns in root

Tags: python, xml, tree, elementtree

number.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ResponseSent>
  <ResponseDate xmlns="http://example.com/schema">
   <emailid>123@test.com</emailid>
    <number>22</number>
    <sent>2017-12-05</sent>
 </ResponseDate>
```

number.py

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('number.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for country in root.findall('ResponseDate'):
    rank = country.find('emailid').text
    name = country.find('number').text
    print(name, rank)
```

Returning empty results, but when I modify the xml to name= instead of xmlns= then it is working. But, how to make this script work with the xmlns.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that `xmlns` without prefix in XML declares *default namespace*, and descendants element without prefix inherit default namespace from ancestor implicitly. Now to find element in namespace you can
define a prefix that references the namespace URI, and use combination of that prefix and target element's local name :

```
....
ns = { 'd': 'http://example.com/schema' }
for country in root.findall('d:ResponseDate', ns):
    rank = country.find('d:emailid', ns).text
    name = country.find('d:number', ns).text
    print(name, rank)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification and solution.